# Assign weightage to variables

Tags: statistics

I want to use statistical method to determine the weightage of some variables. 
Price = W*X1 + W*X2.
X are the variables and W are the weightage.
Is there any statistical method to find W?
Summation of W should equal to 100.

Comment: This does look like a linear model formula.

Comment: But summation of beta in  linear model doesn't equal to 100. Or is there any method to convert the beta to percentage?

Comment: That their sum equals to a pre-specified number means that you are dealing with compositional data. There are linear models for such data, as there are others.

Comment: Can I get the weight of the variables using that model ?

Comment: Yes, that is what linear models do, return the coefficients (weights) of the variables.

Comment: But summation of beta doesn't equal to 100. What should I do to make it equal to 100?

Comment: For a compositional linear model yes it will.

Comment: Statistics questions should go to Cross Validated: stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok so do you have any suggestion to my question?